# jquery scrollto + addclass to div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scrollto

I'm using scrollto, and I'm wanting to have a class added when it scrolls to the next div. Using removeClass/addClass would work? I don't know where I would place it so when scrollto, scrolls to the current .column div it adds the "selected" class as well.

Coles notes version: I'm looking to the current div highlighted when scrolled to.

This is the scrollto code I'm using:

```
function scrollToPosition(element) {
    if (element !== undefined) {
        $(".wrap").scrollTo(element, 800, {
            margin: true
        });
    }
}

$(function() {

    //Create an Array of posts
    var posts = $('.column');
    var position = 0; //Start Position
    var next = $('#rightControl');
    var prev = $('#leftControl').hide();

    //Better performance to use Id selectors than class selectors
    next.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to next position
        prev.show();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);
        if (position === posts.length - 1) {
            next.hide();
        }
    });

    prev.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to prev position    
        next.show();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div class="arrows">
<div class="nav_arrow">
     <div class="control" id="leftControl"></div>
         <div class="control" id="rightControl"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <div  class="column"></div>
        <div  class="column"></div>
        <div  class="column"></div>
        <div  class="column"></div>
        <div  class="column"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this untested code!

```
function scrollToPosition(element) {
if (element !== undefined) {
   $(element).addClass('selected')
   $(element).siblings().removeClass('selected')
    $(".wrap").scrollTo(element, 800, {
        margin: true
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't scroll after implementing that change. I under it is untested, I'll keep playing around. Any help would be greatly appreciated! - EDIT: placed .addClass and .siblings. below .scrollto

Comment: It doesn't remove the class from previous div.

Comment: @frayed_dna sorry a typo, `siblings` should be `siblings()`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you should just be able to do:

```
$('.someclass').removeClass('someclass');    
posts[position].addClass('someclass');
```

right after your call to scrollToPosition.